# How can I use nock.js to mock node-webshot requests?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, nock

What is proper way to mock requests sent by [node Webshot](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot) during a test using [nock.js](https://github.com/nock/nock)?

I tried following code to capture mocked response of http://example.com/foo.html as `foo.png` but the mock doesn't seem to work.

```js
const nock = require("nock");
const webshot = require("webshot");

describe("mock webshot request", function(){
  this.timeout(20000);
  beforeEach(function(){
    nock("http://example.com").persist().get("/foo.html").reply(200, "<h1>Foo</h1>");
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  it("captures mocked response", function(done){
    webshot("http://example.com/foo.html", "foo.png",function(err) {
      nock.isDone();
      if(!err) done();
    });
  });
});
```

Edit:

The solution was to pass mocked response body to Webshot rather than url:

```
webshot("<h1>Foo</h1>", ...
```

Comment: Your are mocking `foo.html` but testing `foor.html`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the typo. The question is now edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nock` expects the http request to happen in the same process.

*Note:* `node-webshot` is a wrapper for PhantonJS which run in another process.

In your case `Nock` is setup in one process, but the http request happens in another process. So you cannot mock http request done by `node-webshot` like the way your are currently doing.

What you need is support for mocking http request built into `node-webshot` i.e you will have to add this feature to `node-webshot` if it doesn't have it.